# How can I include a list of relationships specific to each node returned in the unwind block, in a Neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a graph where members of an organisation, have one or several relationships to that organisation, and members have incidents, I'm am attempting to return a list of incidents, each including the associated member and a list of their relationships to the organisation.

the graph structure:
`(org)<-[MEMBER_OF|ADMIN_OF|MANAGER_OF|VISITOR_OF]-(member)-[:HAS]->(incidents)`

The query I'm current attempting:

```
MATCH (incidents:Incident)<-[:HAS]-(member:Person)-[rels]->(org:Org {
  orgId: $orgId
})

WITH org,
     member,
    rels,
     collect(incidents) AS collectedIncidents
UNWIND collectedIncidents AS incident
RETURN incident {
       . *,
         org:properties(org),
         member:properties(member),
         roles: rels
       } AS result
  ORDER BY incident.createdAt DESC
  SKIP $skip
  LIMIT $limit
```

The result after I created **2 incidents on one member**:

```
[ { member: { 
       createdAt: 1598524633129,
       uuid: '5f430e1b-29d1-49bf-bbcc-fe1b68400378',
    },
    org: { createdAt: 1598524632522,
       name: 'Murder Hornet Inc',
       uuid: '1a69e9a1-4126-4557-b1ff-8f621b25e23d',
       orgId: 'MHI',
       updatedAt: 1598524632522 },
    roles:
     Relationship {
       identity: 167,
       start: 156,
       end: 155,
       type: 'ADMIN_OF',
       properties: {} 
     },
    uuid: '42050b82-f777-4a8a-a063-9bc43e4cf80d',
    createdAt: 1598524637746,
    },
  { member: { 
       createdAt: 1598524633129,
       uuid: '5f430e1b-29d1-49bf-bbcc-fe1b68400378',
     },
    org: { 
       createdAt: 1598524632522,
       name: 'Murder Hornet Inc',
       uuid: '1a69e9a1-4126-4557-b1ff-8f621b25e23d',
       orgId: 'MHI'
     },
    roles:
     Relationship {
       identity: 167,
       start: 156,
       end: 155,
       type: 'ADMIN_OF',
       properties: {} 
      },
     uuid: '21c86703-4f7b-4c67-8344-0131b011b925',
     createdAt: 1598524637746,
    },
  { member: { 
       createdAt: 1598524633129,
       uuid: '5f430e1b-29d1-49bf-bbcc-fe1b68400378',
    },
    org:
     { createdAt: 1598524632522,
       name: 'Murder Hornet Inc',
       uuid: '1a69e9a1-4126-4557-b1ff-8f621b25e23d',
       orgId: 'MHI',
       updatedAt: 1598524632522 },
    roles:
     Relationship {
       identity: 165,
       start: 156,
       end: 155,
       type: 'MEMBER_OF',
       properties: {} },
    uuid: '42050b82-f777-4a8a-a063-9bc43e4cf80d',
    createdAt: 1598524637746
    },
  { member:
     { 
       createdAt: 1598524633129,
       uuid: '5f430e1b-29d1-49bf-bbcc-fe1b68400378',
      },
    org:
     { createdAt: 1598524632522,
       name: 'Murder Hornet Inc',
       uuid: '1a69e9a1-4126-4557-b1ff-8f621b25e23d',
       orgId: 'MHI',
      },
    roles:
     Relationship {
       identity: 165,
       start: 156,
       end: 155,
       type: 'MEMBER_OF',
       properties: {} },
    uuid: '21c86703-4f7b-4c67-8344-0131b011b925',
    createdAt: 1598524637746,
 } 
]
```

Note that here, I've created **2 incidents on one member**, and I get 4 results back. I've also attempted to collect the `rels` in the `WITH` statement, which provides some equally odd results.

How can I get a list of unique incidents, including the related member, and the relationships that member has to the org? Ideally I would like just the relationship type in an array (given that there could be one or several relationships to the organisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `type()` and `collect()` functions to extract the type of relationship from `rels` and have them as a list.

`collect(DISTINCT type(rels))` will leave you with distinct roles as an array of strings.

You might want to consider ensuring that you have `DISTINCT` in your `collect()` of incidents so that you don't have duplicate results when you unwind.

Your query when then look something like the following:

```
MATCH (incidents:Incident)<-[:HAS]-(member:Person)-[rels]->(org:Org {
  orgId: $orgId
})

WITH org, member, collect(DISTINCT type(rels)) as roles, collect(DISTINCT incidents) AS collectedIncidents
UNWIND collectedIncidents AS incident
RETURN incident {
       . *,
         org:properties(org),
         member:properties(member),
         roles: roles
       } AS result
  ORDER BY incident.createdAt DESC
  SKIP $skip
  LIMIT $limit
```